# Group extension of the natural numbers? What is this called?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $\{g_1, ... , g_n\}$ be a multiplicative group and define the set $S = \mathbb{N}g_1 + ... \mathbb{N}g_n$.  Define multiplication in $S$ by expanding the product $(a_1 g_1 + ... a_n g_n)(b_1 g_1 + ... b_n g_n)$ in the natural way.

Comment: I would call it a group semiring (if $\mathbb{N}$ also contains $0$). Not sure this is a standard name though.

Comment: If $G = \{g_1, \dots, g_n\}$ and instead of $\Bbb N$ you use a ring $R$, then this is called the group ring $R[G]$: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_ring